# How do I specify the units when using diff on a datetime vector?

Tags: r

Consider the vector of datetimes:

```
x=as.POSIXct(c("2019-01-01 14:59:00 EST",
    "2019-01-01 23:22:00 EST",
    "2019-01-01 11:48:00 EST",
    "2019-01-01 16:06:00 EST",
    "2019-01-01 03:20:00 EST"))
```

calling `diff(x)` produces

```
Time differences in hours
[1]   8.383333 -11.566667   4.300000 -12.766667
```

The problem with this is `diff` produces numbers in unpredictable units. For example merely adding an element to the original vector with the value "2019-01-01 15:02:00 EST" will cause it to produce a result in minutes rather than hours. Is there a way to specify what units it returns the results in? Adding a `units` parameter doesn't seem to work for `diff` like it does in `difftime`.

Comment: What's the advantage for using `diff` over `difftime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `difftime` on the adjacent elements by removing one from the start and one from the end

```
difftime(x[-1], x[-length(x)], unit = "min")
#Time differences in mins
#[1]  503 -694  258 -766
```